# VBA Excel: wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment on call function

Tags: excel, vba, arguments

I get a compile error on that code below. Maybe someone can help me.

"Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" 
for
Call Alternative(folderspec, f1.Name)

It used to work a day ago for some reason.

```
Sub WM()
Const folderspec = "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\wm"
Dim fs, f, f1, fc

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFolder(folderspec)
    Set fc = f.Files
    For Each f1 In fc
        If UCase(Right(f1, 3)) = "XLS" Then 'Excel File gefunden
        Call Alternative(folderspec, f1.Name)

        End If
    Next

End Sub

Sub Alternative()

Active.Workbook.UsedRange.Replace "Anteilklasse ", "", xlPart

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" means that you need 2 parameters in `Sub Alternative`, as you are passing them with the `Call`:

```
Sub Alternative(folderspec As String, f1Name As String)    
    ActiveWorkbook.UsedRange.Replace "Anteilklasse ", "", xlPart    
End Sub
```

- Now the compile error should be ok.
- There should not be a dot between Active and Workbook - `ActiveWorkbook` is the correct;

Comment: @FunThomas - It could be that the user is writing [MCVE] and has decided to delete about 20 lines of irrelevant code, where the parameters are used :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I try to open several .xls files in a specific folder and then "sub alternative" should edit those files. I thought i need those parameters to open the files.